# SQL Count across multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, count, sum, union

I need to find the number of occurrences per unique combination of x & y across two tables.

```
  Table1:        Table2:
+----+----+    +----+----+
| x  | y  |    | x  | y  |
+----+----+    +----+----+
| 20 | 10 |    | 20 | 10 |
| 20 | 20 |    | 20 | 20 |
| 20 | 20 |    | 30 | 20 |
| 40 | 10 |    +----+----+
+----+----+
```

Output:

```
+----+----+--------+
| x  | y  | amount |
+----+----+--------+
| 20 | 10 |      2 |
| 20 | 20 |      3 |
| 30 | 20 |      1 |
| 40 | 10 |      1 |
+----+----+--------+
```

Here's my current query:

```
SELECT x, Y, count(*) AS Amount  FROM Table1 
UNION ALL
SELECT X, Y, count(*) AS Amount  FROM Table2 
GROUP BY x, y;
```

This creates duplicate instances of unique combinations of x & y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `COUNT()` on the result of `UNION`:

```
select x,y,count(*) as Amount
from
(SELECT x, Y FROM Table1 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT X, Y FROM Table2)temp
group by x,y
```

Answer (score 0):

I would set up something like this:

```
select
  d.x
  , d.y
  , sum(d.cnt) as cnt
from
  (
    select x, y, count(*) as cnt from table1 group by x, y
    union all
    select x, y, count(*) as cnt from table2 group by x, y
  ) d
group by
  d.x
  , d.y
```

This solution counts the unique entries in both tables and then adds the results together from the two tables.